# Advice on Flexible Pickup System

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

First off, this is my first time posting here and I am new to coding so please for give me for all things.  :)

I am trying to make a flexible pickup system for a game in Unity using C#.  I would like to be able to pick a Pickup Type from a drop down have the code then direct which variable it updates with the minimal number of values for me or future designers to have to adjust.

For Example:
In the game you have a health pickup and a stamina pickup.  I place the same HealthSystemPickup.cs on both game objects. In the inspector I choose if it is a health or stamina pickup type and then adjust the increase or decrease values.  The code will then tell it to either update the health or stamina based on the pickup type selected.   So on and so on for any future pickup types.

What I Have so far:

I have a script that defines the PickupTypes via public enums.
I have another script that is the Pickup itself which allows you to pick from that list of enums and set an increase and decrease value upon a OnTiggerEnter event.

Simple enough and works as long as I am calling specific methods from my health system script, but not based on the PickupType... and that is what I am stuck on.  I am not sure how to direct what methods I am calling based on the PickupType it is.

I'd love advice on where to investigate or direction people have taken to do something similar.

any help would be great!

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a good candidate for using polymorphism. You can define an interface or an abstract superclass that has all the methods your other scripts would interact with, and separate classes (rather than a single class with a type enum) for the health and stamina types. Something like:

```
public abstract class Pickup : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int amount = 10;
    public abstract void PickUp(Player player);
}

public class HealthPickup : Pickup
{
    public override void PickUp(Player player)
    {
         player.Health += amount;
    }
}

public class StaminaPickup
{
    public override void PickUp(Player player)
    {
         player.Stamina += amount;
    }
}
```

When you need to deal with pickups in other classes, you never address `HealthPickup` or `StaminaPickup` directly, you just refer to them as instances of `Pickup`.

Comment: Awesome thanks.  I will investigate that route.  I don't know much about it so it would be a good thing to learn more bout as well.

Comment: Great. If you're happy with the answer please consider marking it accepted and upvoting.